# How do you theme a pager in a specific View?

Tags: 7, views

I have a few views, but each view would have a pager that would be themed differently. How do I go about targetting the pagers of each View for theming?

Answer (score 0):

each view has own class like .view-id-name
so this class or id you can use to CSS your pager for each view

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I must reiterate - I want to change the display output of the pager - changing the text and adding classes.